# Why Transfer-Encoding request header does not interpret correctly?

Tags: http, transfer-encoding

Here is the PHP code for **pg3.php**:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="pg3.php">
<h2><font color="red">::Welcome to Server1: 172.16.24.150::</font></h2>
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>

<?php

if(!empty($_POST["user"])){

  echo $_POST["user"];

}

?>
```

I sent the following request:

```
curl --data "8\r\nuser=mehran\r\n0\r\n" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" "http://172.16.17.10/pg3.php"
```

I got the following response:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="pg3.php">
<h2><font color="red">::Welcome to Server1: 172.16.24.150::</font></h2>
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

As the above shows, **user=meh** is not in the response, while it must be there if Transfer-Encoding works correctly.

What's the problem??
TNX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this example in the documentation](https://everything.curl.dev/http/post#chunked-encoded-posts):

> You send a chunked POST with curl like this:
>
> `curl -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -d "payload to send" http://example.com`

You don't need to try to create the chunked encoded payload yourself. In your case:

```
curl --data "user=mehran" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" "http://172.16.17.10/pg3.php"
```

is enough for `curl` to send:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
...
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

b
user=mehran
0
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. That's the case.